# collapsable master detail gridview structure

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I need an advice for a c# asp.net project.
My client wants to see some reports via the gridview object with master/detail structure.

The main gridview will be full by all master data and each row will have a **+** icon (or button) on the first cells.
When user clicks this icon, the all details data of that master row should be seen under that master row with collaps action.

I can handle the database proccess but i can not figure out the collapsing part.
How can i put some extra rows under the specific row on the gridview object?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks but its for updating or inserting.
Instead , i have found that page, it seems more effective.

[GridView control to show master-child or master-slave data, written in c#, asp.net, and javascript.](http://www.progtalk.com/ViewArticle.aspx?ArticleID=54)

Answer (score 4):

[Matt Berseth](http://mattberseth.com/) has one of the most impresive tutorials on this kind'a stuff

it contains til now [28 tutorials](http://mattberseth.com/blog/gridview/) only on the GridView plus a lot from other asp.net controls as well using jQuery with them. I do learn plenty with him. I really love his work and I just wanna share this with you, you might actually get some good and professional ideas from his code!

Answer (score 2):

There is a CodeProject article with downloadable source:

[GridView inline Master/Detail record display](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/MasterDetail.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another good CodeProject blog. Explains multilevel master/detail without JavaScript.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/MultiNestMDGridview.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is the easiest to use control I've ever run across:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CompleteGridView

Comment: You can find some help for setting it up at:

http://www.adservium.com/CompleteGridView/